# Visual C++ inline x86 assembly: Accessing "this" pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, this, inline-assembly

According to the MSDN documentation the "this" pointer is stored in ECX when using the default [__thiscall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) calling convention for class functions. Despite this certainly being the case when translating regular C++ code I have encountered a problem when trying to access "this" with inline assembly.

Here's the test program:

```
#include <cstdio>

class TestClass
{
    long x;

    public:
        inline TestClass(long x):x(x){}

    public:
        inline long getX1(){return x;}
        inline long getX2()
        {
            _asm
            {
                mov eax,dword ptr[ecx]
            }
        }
};
int main()
{
    TestClass c(42);

    printf("c.getX1() = %d\n",c.getX1());
    printf("c.getX2() = %d\n",c.getX2());

    return 0;
}
```

The two Get functions are translated like this:

```
?getX1@TestClass@@QAEJXZ (public: long __thiscall TestClass::getX1(void)):
  00000000: 8B 01              mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]
  00000002: C3                 ret

?getX2@TestClass@@QAEJXZ (public: long __thiscall TestClass::getX2(void)):
  00000000: 8B 01              mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]
  00000002: C3                 ret
```

I think it's safe to say that these two functions are identical. Nevertheless, here's the output from the program:

```
c.getX1() = 42
c.getX2() = 1
```

Obviously "this" is *not* stored in ECX when the second Get function is invoked, so my question is: How do I ensure that class functions containing inline assembly follow the calling convention and/or are invoked the same way as regular/non-inlined functions?

EDIT: The main function is translated like this:

```
_main:
  00000000: 51                 push        ecx
  00000001: 6A 2A              push        2Ah
  00000003: 68 00 00 00 00     push        offset $SG3948
  00000008: E8 00 00 00 00     call        _printf
  0000000D: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  00000010: 8D 0C 24           lea         ecx,[esp]
  00000013: E8 00 00 00 00     call        ?getX2@TestClass@@QAEJXZ
  00000018: 50                 push        eax
  00000019: 68 00 00 00 00     push        offset $SG3949
  0000001E: E8 00 00 00 00     call        _printf
  00000023: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
  00000025: 83 C4 0C           add         esp,0Ch
  00000028: C3                 ret
```

Comment: What is the corresponding disassembly of `main()`? Particularly with your functions declared `inline`, the assembly code you've shown won't even necessarily be used.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Just inserted the code for the main function in my post.

Comment: It looks like the compiler has optimised the entire object completely out of existence. Which is sort of surprising, given that it doesn't know what you're actually doing in the `_asm` block.

Comment: Try making the constructor _not_ inline, and see if the object construction is still optimized away.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Yes, the call to the first non-asm Get function is simply expanded inline directly into the code, but the second one is called explicitly with a call instruction. It still seems a little weird that adding inline asm to the function changes the calling convention :?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Just tried it, didn't make a difference (and nor should it reallý).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to make the function work corretly (ie. pass "this" in ECX):

**testclass.hpp**:

```
class TestClass
{
    long x;

    public:
        inline TestClass(long x):x(x){}

    public:
        long getX1();
        long getX2();
};
```

**testclass.cpp**:

```
#include "testclass.hpp"

long TestClass::getX1()
{
    return x;
}
long TestClass::getX2()
{
    _asm
    {
        mov eax,dword ptr[ecx]
    }
}
```

**testmain.cpp**:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "testclass.hpp"

int main()
{
    TestClass c(42);

    printf("c.getX1() = %d\n",c.getX1());
    printf("c.getX2() = %d\n",c.getX2());

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
c.getX1() = 42
c.getX2() = 42
```

The problem is that inlined class functions in MSVC 2010 not necessarily follow the calling conventions specified by MSDN. I don't think this is a bug, but you should at least be aware of it if you are planning to use inline assembly in inlined functions. My advice is that you don't do it. If you need inline assembly in a class function keep the declaration and implementation separated.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know whether you're misreading the documentation, or whether
it's poorly written, but `__thiscall` does **not** mean that the `this`
pointer is *stored* in ECX; it means that the pointer to the object is
*passed* in ECX.  In larger functions, I've seen it move from one
register to another in different places in the function, and in some
cases, I've seen it spilled to memory.  You cannot count on it being in
ECX.  And where it will be can change depending on other code in the
function, and the optimization flags passed to the compiler.

In your case, the issue is further complicated by the fact that your 
functions are inline, and probably have been inlined.  (Except that 
`_asm` may inhibit inlining.)  Constant propagation (a very simple and
widely used optimization technique) will almost certainly mean that your
call to `c.getX1()` will just use `42`, with no function call and no
access to `c` whatever.

In general, inline assembler is a tricky issue, precisely because you
don't know what registers the compiler is using for what.  Normally, in
addition to actual assembler instructions, there will be directives to
tell the compiler things like which registers and which variables you
use, and you will be able to refer to the variables themselves in the
assembler, and other such information.  Unless you use these, you can
assume very, very little with regards to inline assembler.

But each compiler has its own rules.  Often with special syntax.
Something like `mov eax, [cx].x` for example, or `mov eax, x`, might be
what the Microsoft inline assembler needs.  At any rate, there's no way
from what you've written that the compiler could possibly deduce that
you're accessing `c.x`.  And since all other uses have been eliminated
by constant propagation, it would be a very poor compiler which even
generated a variable `c`.

EDIT:

FWIW: The documentation of Microsoft's inline assembler is at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.71%29.aspx.  I
haven't looked at it in detail, but there is a section about "Using C or
C++ Symbols in __asm Blocks".  This will probably explain how you can
access `x` in the inline assembler in a way that the compiler will know
that `x` has been accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, from what I've seen of the MS compiler, is that the compiler doesn't know that `[ecx]` is the same as `this->x`, so the compiler doesn't know the member variable is being accessed (tracing the data flow through a function is tricky).

The compiler has optimised away the call to the constructor of the object and inlined the `getX1` with the constant that would have been passed to the constructor. This means the object is not correctly constructed when the call to `getX2` is made since, from the compiler's view, the function `getX2` does not access any of the members so it doesn't need to be correctly constructed. In the MS compiler, I've not seen a way to tell the compiler that member variables are being used, even when using `[ecx]TestClass.x`.

And, what has been mentioned many times, `inline` is often ignored by the compiler, the compiler has a better idea of when it's best to inline code. In this case, functions with `_asm` blocks aren't inlined, other functions are inlined / rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is actually stored within `ecx`, at least the address where the object would have been if it was not optimized away:

```
00000010: 8D 0C 24           lea         ecx,[esp]
```

The problem is that optimizer does not really understand the assembly code, so the responsibility of code correctness is on you. It just removes the object since it sees that it can just inline the `42` into the `printf` call, like:

```
printf("c.getX1() = %d\n",42);
```

To make it work, define `getX2` as `noinline`:

```
long __declspec(noinline) getX2() { ... }
```

This makes the optimizer to look at it as a total black-box, so it  does not make any assumptions regarding whether it accesses the `c` object or not. This indeed works for me, but it is not documented.

Instead, I recommend you to do not use inline assembly with MSVC, it is not even supported for 64-bit compilations. Use MASM instead, this will also eliminate future frustration.

Comment: I just tried it, but (as expected) it didn't make a difference. Besides, the function containing inline asm (GetX2) is *not* expanded inline if you look at the code in the main function. Nevertheless, you are right that using inline asm in MSVC probably isn't such a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @Dragonion: 1) What compiler you use? I tested in on MSVC8. 2) It is not relevant whether it's expanded or not, the optimizer is able to optimize across function boundaries. The `__declspec` in my case or some other circumstances (like linking with an obj without LTCG) prevents it from doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've inlined the function, the compiler doesn't know that it has to set `ecx` correctly prior to invoking the asm code, especially as the rest of the function doesn't use any object properties or methods.

Try declaring and defining the methods non-`inline` first.  It might be better to make `getX2` a non-inline non-member function defined in a different translation unit, so the compiler is restricted in its optimization opportunities.

Comment: You are right that the compiler doesn't place "this" in ECX (my question is as a matter of fact why it doesn't do that), but making it non-inline will not solve this, unless Visual C++ totally ignores the C++ standard.

Comment: @Dragonion `_asm` is not part of the standard.  If you look at your disassembly, the compiler has completely inlined the object so much that it doesn't exist in memory.

Comment: I know, but a function must still behave the same whether it's inline or not. Could you imagine having a function return 1 if it was inlined and 0 otherwise?

Comment: @Dragonion `_asm` is not in the standard, so whatever the compiler does is still compliant with the standard.

Comment: The problem is the calling convention which should be the same whether the function is inline or not. The _asm keyword really isn't the issue here.

Comment: @Dragonion: ) The standard does not say anything about calling conventions. 2) In this case the calling convention is actually correct, i.e. the compiler generates a correct call.

Comment: You are right that the calling conventions are Microsoft specific, but if the compiler does indeed invoke the function correctly with respect to the __thiscall calling convention, how come ECX doesn't contain "this" inside the function?

Comment: @Dragonion it doesn't need to, because the function doesn't use `this`.